# Cannot build after adding ios widget to existing react-native project: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, widget

I have an existing react-native project, after create a new ios widget target, do not modify anything, then build, I got the compile error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_swift_getOpaqueTypeConformance", referenced from:
      money24h_widgetExtension.money24h_widget.body.getter : some in money24h_widget-a02bbe01bccb475d9f71a206fd2ab70cfae065911d2c861c9ce9e26d51e21bf8.o
      associated type witness table accessor for SwiftUI.View.Body : SwiftUI.View in money24h_widgetExtension.money24h_widgetEntryView : SwiftUI.View in money24h_widgetExtension in money24h_widget-a02bbe01bccb475d9f71a206fd2ab70cfae065911d2c861c9ce9e26d51e21bf8.o
      associated type witness table accessor for SwiftUI.Widget.Body : SwiftUI.WidgetConfiguration in money24h_widgetExtension.money24h_widget : SwiftUI.Widget in money24h_widgetExtension in money24h_widget-a02bbe01bccb475d9f71a206fd2ab70cfae065911d2c861c9ce9e26d51e21bf8.o
      associated type witness table accessor for SwiftUI.PreviewProvider.Previews : SwiftUI.View in money24h_widgetExtension.money24h_widget_Previews : SwiftUI.PreviewProvider in money24h_widgetExtension in money24h_widget-a02bbe01bccb475d9f71a206fd2ab70cfae065911d2c861c9ce9e26d51e21bf8.o
      l_get_witness_table qd__7SwiftUI19WidgetConfigurationHD2_AaBP0C3KitE11descriptionyQrAA18LocalizedStringKeyVFQOyAcDE24configurationDisplayNameyQrAGFQOyAD06IntentD0Vy24money24h_widgetExtension0dM0CAK0n1_O9EntryViewVG_Qo__Qo_HO in money24h_widget-a02bbe01bccb475d9f71a206fd2ab70cfae065911d2c861c9ce9e26d51e21bf8.o
  "_swift_getTypeByMangledNameInContextInMetadataState", referenced from:
      ___swift_instantiateConcreteTypeFromMangledNameAbstract in money24h_widget-a02bbe01bccb475d9f71a206fd2ab70cfae065911d2c861c9ce9e26d51e21bf8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Swift version is configured to 5 already.

It seems no one else got this issue.

How can I build it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, after half of an hour searching.

Found the same case [here](https://ospfranco.github.io/post/2020/08/14/ios-14-widgets-and-react-native/)

[Solution here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29246#issuecomment-663986438) from Github.

Change `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` from:

```
"\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"",
```

to:

```
"\"$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.2/$(PLATFORM_NAME)\"",
```

Comment: Check Finder to see if that directory actually exists in the Xcode.app. As of Xcode 14.3.1, the folder is `swift-5.5` instead of `swift-5.2`, and I assume it will change in future versions.